# nested form in Activeadmin with dropdown selection - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have the next database design:

A **order** can have a **size** and a **size** can be in many **orders**.

For example:

> Order 1 has a size attribute equal to medium
>
> Order 2 has a size attribute equal to medium

I want to be able to select a size when I create a Order in active admin.

Order model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :order_size
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_size, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Order size model:

```
class OrderSize < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :orders
end
```

Also, OrderSize table has to have a order_id column?

I don't know if the models are rights but activeadmin is giving me this error:

```
undefined method `order_id' for #<Order:0x007fb980e34b80>
```

**My activeadmin models**

Order Size:

```
ActiveAdmin.register OrderSize do
  permit_params :name
end
```

Order:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  permit_params :due_date, :comments, :approved, :order_size_id,
                order_size_attributes: [:id, :name,:_destroy]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :due_date
      f.input :order_size
      f.input :comments
      f.input :approved
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if the models are rights but activeadmin is giving me
>   this error:
>
> undefined method `order_id' for Order:0x007fb980e34b80

Yes, Rails expects a `foreign_key(order_id)` of *associated model(order)* for *ObjectRelationalMapping(ORM)* to communicate with *RDBMS*. Create a migration for `order_id` and run `rake db:migrate` to resolve the problem.

Also the *association name* for `belongs_to` or `has_one` should be ***singular***.

```
class OrderSize < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Additionally, you shouldn't have `order_size_id` in `orders` as the association is `has_one :order_size`. Instead as I pointed out above, you should have `order_id` in `order_sizes`.

Comment: But I will be able to have  the same order size (for example medium) in different orders?

Comment: @exsnake I'm afraid you should change your associations to satisfy that!

Comment: @pavin Hmmm can you help me with that? I asume that an Order can have just one Size and a size can be part of many orders. I'm using `belongs_to` wrong?

Comment: @exsnake I may be wrong with my previous comment! Seems like your associations are correct to achieve what you want.